# jQuery - on enter key submit text - line break still inserted into textarea

Tags: jquery, line-breaks

I am having a small problem on posting some text from a textarea as soon as the enter key is pressed.

The entered text gets appended to a div with a neat effect and the entered text is then removed from the textarea, which all works fine. However, when you hit enter a line break is actually still inserted in the textarea, right after which the text is appended and removed. So for a split second you can see the line break being added, which doesn't look nice at all.

How do I prevent the insertion of a line break?

Thanks!
Dennis

UPDATE:

Some code here. I use the keyup.

```
$('#postDiv').on('keyup', '#posttext', function(e) {
    if ((e.which == 13) && !event.shiftKey) {
        post($(this));
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you attaching to the keyup or keydown event? Post some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#postDiv').on('keydown', '#posttext', function(e) {
    if ((e.which == 13) && !event.shiftKey) {
        post($(this));
        return false
    }
});
```

Note the change to keydown, in order to block the default action

Comment: This is where you wanna be `:)`

Comment: @paulslater19 oh but why do you return false?

Comment: @Dennis `return false` will prevent the `line break` from being inserted in your textarea.

Comment: It will prevent the new line being inserted. I think the same could be done through `e.preventDefault()`. `return false` also stops propagation (i.e. the event bubbling up the DOM). But you probably don't have to worry about it too much